# Post data to facebook

Tags: facebook-oauth

i am able to update user status using the following URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/944254185/feed?method=post&
```

message=hello
&access_token=4E35zZCu8xtLBExPJvbGCmYOXFOGe8P

In GOOGLE it requires a URL whcih contains oauth_nonce,oauth_signature,oauth_token,oauth_version etc

but in facebook to change user status and create album didnt need these parameters.

So will those parameters be required for uploading photos to facebook.

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved

Facebook is not expecting header that contains parameters like oauth_nounce,oauth_signature,oauth_version etc